# PHP 7.2 Function create_function() is deprecated, create_function('$s', 'return \'DISTINCT\';'))

Tags: php

I have use on my site  PHP Version 7.2
The problem I am having is with a deprecated function in my wordpress plugin php

`add_filter('posts_distinct', create_function('$s', 'return \'DISTINCT\';'));`

I have already tried:

`add_filter('posts_distinct', function($s) {return DISTINCT;});`

but it doesnt work

Thanks!

Comment: You need to quote the word distinct, `'DISTINCT'` because it is a string

Comment: it's work perfect! but i use double quote string, thank you!